# How can I capture an entire image from a canvas?

Tags: wpf, image-processing, canvas, save

I am working on a project to number features on an image. Each item being numbered is a textblock object being printed on top of a canvas that has a jpg(or bmp/gif/png) drawn to it's background using an image brush. 
When it comes time to save the graphic I want to have two options, one to save it as a new jpg (or other format) that has the textblock objects rendered into it. or option b which would be to save the placements of those textblocks to a seperate file (XML, XAML what have you) so you could come back and continue to edit the entries.

Here is some of my code.
This is where I am trying to save the image

```
private void miSaveImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageBrush bi = (ImageBrush)canvas.Background;
        Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(canvas);
        double pw = (bi.ImageSource as BitmapSource).PixelWidth;
        double ph = (bi.ImageSource as BitmapSource).PixelHeight;
        double px = (bi.ImageSource as BitmapSource).DpiX;
        double py = (bi.ImageSource as BitmapSource).DpiY;
        //Get the actual width and height of the image, then the dpi and render an image of it
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)pw, (int)ph, px*96, py*96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);

        rtb.Render(canvas);
        //create the encoder and save the image data to it.
        BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

        try
        {
            //eventually I need to make this a save dialog but that will come later.
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            pngEncoder.Save(ms);
            ms.Close();

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Sample.png", ms.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString(), "Problem saving image", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }

    }
```

This is the code I use to load the image

```
//Global members   
Image i;    
static Size _Size = new Size();   


 private void miLoadImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create OpenFileDialog 
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();


            // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
            dlg.Filter = @"All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp|
                        JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|
                        PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|
                        JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|
                        GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif|
                        BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
            // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
            if (result == true)
            {
                // Open document 
                string filename = dlg.FileName;
                Uri uri = new Uri(@dlg.FileName, UriKind.Relative);

                //Use canvas rather than image
                ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
                ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
                canvas.Background = ib;

                if (i == null)
                    i = new Image();
                i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName));
                _Size = new Size(i.Source.Width, i.Source.Height);

            }
        }
```

Here is the code I use to write the text to the image.

```
 public void WriteTextToImage(Point position)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)cpColor.SelectedColor);
        //Get something to write on (not an old receipt...)
        TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
        //Say something useful... well something atleast... 
        textBlock.Text = tbCurrentLabel.Text;
        textBlock.FontSize = slFontSize.Value;
        textBlock.Foreground = brush;
        Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, position.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(textBlock, position.Y);
        canvas.Children.Add(textBlock);

        //Need to update the canvas, was not seeing children before doing this.
        canvas.UpdateLayout();

        //Iterate the label text
        IterateLabel();
    }
```

Right now I am only getting a corner of the image that is currently visible in the canvas, and that is being cropped down, by fiddling with the DPI and _Size values I can change how much of the image is shown, but it is static to that one image (If I load a different image all the values are wrong and again I only get a small portion of the image)

If someone could please help me pull my head out of (ahem) I would be most grateful! 
TIA

Comment: have u checked the answer

Answer (score 0):

*Save entire `Canvas`*

```
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Cnv.ActualWidth, (int)Cnv.ActualHeight, 100.0, 100.0, PixelFormats.Default);
        bmp.Render(Cnv);                       

        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

        System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create("G:\\Canvas.png");
        encoder.Save(stream);
        stream.Close();
```

*Save only Background*

```
    BitmapFrame bmp = (BitmapFrame)(Cnv.Background as ImageBrush).ImageSource;

    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(bmp);

    System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Create("G:\\Canvas.png");
    encoder.Save(stream);
    stream.Close();
```